# Django - Optimizing displaying each group of rows that sums to a specific amount

Tags: python, django

I am looking for the optimal solution to the following problem:

Let's say you have a group of people, each spending different amounts of money on different transactions. Transactions are stored in the following table:

```
class Transactions(models.Model):
     amount = DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
     created_on = DateField(auto_now_add=True)
     t_person = ForeignKey('Person')
```

Given a specific date, I would like to find each person that spends over a certain amount in the 30 days following that date. More specifically, I would like to return a list of each transaction a user made, grouped by user, along with the total amount that they spent. Here is my first attempt:

```
def get_transaction(amount, month_start, month_end):
    total_transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(created_on__gte=month_start, created_on__lte=month_end)
    distinct_people = total_transactions.distinct('t_person').values('t_person')
    amounts = []
    query = []

    for p in distinct_people:
        transactions = total_transactions.filter(t_person=p['t_person'])
        p_sum = transactions.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
        if p_sum['amount__sum'] >= float(amount):
            amounts.append(p_sum['amount__sum'])
            query.append(transactions)

    return zip(amounts, query)
```

This works fine for now, but my fear is that this is an inefficient way to accomplish something that can hopefully be done simpler. Is there an easier way to get this done?

Comment: Have you looked at [the Aggregation section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/) of the Django ORM docs?  I think you might find that helpful.  You can push more of the work down to the database level rather than using loops and conditionals in Python.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston Yeah I have, but never came across anything relevant to what I was looking for. Any specific suggestions?